# Downloaded image doesn't always show up immediately

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

For some reason my photoimg will not update consistantly  , sometimes it does sometimes it doesn't.

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with async calls but I've been stuck trying to figure out the root reason why its not updating. So this is in my mainVC and for a user to upload/update image they go to the settingsVC and when they segue back sometimes it shows to the updated image, other times still shows the old image , other times showing nothing . But oddly if I click on my settings and dismiss it then the image will show updated.

So I think my issue lies where I'm calling my method and my async queue.

```
func fetchProfileImage() {

    Dataservice.dataService.USERS_REF_CURRENT_PROFILE_IMAGE.downloadURL { (url, error) in
        if error != nil {     
        }
        else {

            let url = url?.downloadURL

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, resonse, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("Fetching did not download \(error.debugDescription)")

                }

                if let data = data {
                    print("Fetching Image did download data")

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.profilePhoto.image = UIImage(data: data)
                    }
                }
            }).resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the log. (Also put a print in the empty error case).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the built in download mechanism, which always presents callbacks on the main thread*:

```
let image: UIImage!
let ref = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: Dataservice.dataService.USERS_REF_CURRENT_PROFILE_IMAGE)
ref.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
  if let error = error {
    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
  } else {
    // Data for your profile image is returned
    image = UIImage(data: data!)
  }
}
```

*unless you explicitly change the thread by providing your own queue ;)

Comment: Ive tried this concept as well but still get the inconsistency of Image loading . What happens is i print out Imaged returned right before image is set but the sometimes does not get set my guess is its between where I'm calling my method or threading.

Answer (score -3):

after you perform async, you need to back to main thread to set the download image

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  DispatchQueue.main.sync {
    self.profilePhoto.image = UIImage(data: data)
  }
}
```

Comment: OP is already using `DispatchQueue.main.async` to update the UI on the main thread.

Comment: That did nothing but crash my program @rudydydy

Comment: where you calling fetchProfileImage()  method

Comment: Im calling it in viewDidappear but i tried calling in all viewWillAppear and didLoad still getting inconsistency